# Jquery live - focusin fires multiple times

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery 1.4.1. I have HTML input elements which created dynamically.  I have assigned "focusin" event all input elements. While loading page, it is triggers only once while focusing each input element.

Problem is, When I minimize and maximize the page, focus event is fired multiple times. Finally it show "Stack overflow at line 0".

```
   $('input').live("focusin",function(objectRef) {
        alert("focusin event");

    })
```

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 16):

Don't worry. It only happens when you call `alert()`. But I don't really understand why clicking the OK button on the alert box will trigger the event multiple times.

Try this instead and it will only fires once, as expected.

```
$('input').live("focusin",function(objectRef) {
    //alert("focusin event");
    $("#some_div").append('focus!');
})
```

Same as `focus`, `click`, and other events.

Comment: "It only happens when you call alert()" true

Comment: Just came across this issue. Glad I know that know.

Comment: Very interesting.